# load file from relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, relative-path

I am currently doing this:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("C:/NewsFeed/NewsFeed/App_Data/WorldNews.xml");
```

But I'd like to use a relative path, so I I've tried the following:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("~/App_Data/WorldNews.xml");
```

And set the property, Copty to Output Directory, to "Copy Always".

But I'm getting the following error:

*An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: A part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\App_Data\WorldNews.xml' was not found.*

Any help please?

Comment: checkout the following link [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XDocument.Load` doesn't know anything about mapping paths. Instead, you should use [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath) to map the path, then pass the result into `XDocument.Load`:

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WorldNews.xml");
var feedXml = XDocument.Load(path);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed. Will flag as accepted in 9 minutes :)